# Async function in Converting object to another object in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would like to implement an async function in converting the object to another object then in saving to the database.

```
public List<Order> GetOrdersFromTradeGeckoCount()
{
    string orderLimit = base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.HasValue ? base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.Value.ToString() : "250";
    string filters = string.Format("?status=finalized&limit={0}", orderLimit);
    HttpResponseMessage response = _requestHelper.GetHttpResponse("orders" + filters);
    var tgOrders = GetOrdersResponse(response);
    //Async Convert and Save Order
    ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(tgOrders);
    return ConvertToORouterOrdersCount(tgOrders);
}
```

I would like this method `ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(tgOrders);` will run in the background and will return the Count of Orders from this `ConvertToORouterOrdersCount(tgOrders)` before the conversion is done.

Please help me to change the implementation to asynchronous.

```
public async void ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(List<TGOrder> tgOrders)
{
    var orderMgr = new OrderDAC();
    var orders = new List<Order>(tgOrders.Count());
    foreach (TGOrder tgOrder in tgOrders)
    {
        try
        {
            var order = new Order();
            var orderId = TryConvertInt64(CleanUpOrderId(tgOrder.order_number));

            if (orderId == null) continue;

            var tempOrderId = string.Format("{0}{1}", base.StoreId, orderId.Value);
            order.OrderId = TryConvertInt64(tempOrderId).Value;
            order.StoreOrderId = tgOrder.id.ToString();
            order.WarehouseOrderId = tgOrder.order_number;

            var orderFromDb = orderMgr.GetOrder(order.OrderId, base.StoreId);
            if (orderFromDb != null) continue; // make sure we only import new order(i.e. doesn't exists in database)

            // shipping address
            var tgShippingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.shipping_address_id);
            if (tgShippingAddress == null) continue;

            order.ShipFirstName = tgShippingAddress.first_name;
            order.ShipLastName = tgShippingAddress.last_name;
            order.ShipCompanyName = tgShippingAddress.company_name;
            order.ShipAddress1 = tgShippingAddress.address1;
            order.ShipAddress2 = tgShippingAddress.address2;
            order.ShipCity = tgShippingAddress.suburb;
            order.ShipState = tgShippingAddress.state;
            order.ShipPostalCode = tgShippingAddress.zip_code;
            order.ShipCountry = tgShippingAddress.country;
            order.ShipPhoneNumber = tgShippingAddress.phone_number;

            order.CustomerEmail = tgOrder.email;

            // billing address
            var tgBillingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.billing_address_id);
            if (tgBillingAddress == null) continue;

            // line items
            var lineItems = GetOrderLineItems(tgOrder.id);
            foreach (TGOrderLineItem lineItem in lineItems)
            {
                var ol = new OrderLine();
                if (lineItem.variant_id.HasValue)
                {
                    var variant = GetVariant(lineItem.variant_id.Value);
                    if (variant == null) continue;
                    ol.ProductName = variant.product_name;
                    ol.SKU = variant.sku;
                    ol.ThreePLSKU = ol.SKU;
                    ol.Qty = Convert.ToInt16(TryGetDecimal(lineItem.quantity));
                    ol.OrderId = order.OrderId;
                    ol.Price = TryGetDecimal(lineItem.price);
                    ol.SubTotal = (ol.Qty * ol.Price);
                    ol.StoreOrderLineId = Convert.ToString(lineItem.id);
                    order.OrderLines.Add(ol);
                }
            }
            var validator = new Validator(base.Task);
            if (validator.IsValidOrder(order))
            {
                orderMgr.Add(order);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendError(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt674882.aspx

But I think what you want to look at, would be to wrap your foreach loop up as a multi-threaded operation, and make use of async in that way.

Comment: can you please brief your question it is a bit confusing

Comment: Is there an async version of the database call `orderMgr.GetOrder`? and is the call to `orderMgr.Add(order);` a database call? If so is there also a async version?

Comment: No. It is all synchronous

Answer (score 0):

To really have a advantage of the async and await the underlying calls should have async versions, for example the database calls should be async, don't know if you use EF or just plain `SqlCommand` but both have async versions of their calls.

Other calls that can be async is HTTP calls.

I have edited youre code with the assumption you are able to convert the underlying code to async.

```
public async Task<List<Order> GetOrdersFromTradeGeckoCount()
{
        string orderLimit = base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.HasValue ? base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.Value.ToString() : "250";
        string filters = string.Format("?status=finalized&limit={0}", orderLimit);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _requestHelper.GetHttpResponseAsync("orders" + filters).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var tgOrders = GetOrdersResponse(response);
        //Async Convert and Save Order
        await ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(tgOrders).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await ConvertToORouterOrdersCountAsync(tgOrders).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(List<TGOrder> tgOrders)
{
    var orderMgr = new OrderDAC();
    var orders = new List<Order>(tgOrders.Count());
    foreach (TGOrder tgOrder in tgOrders)
    {
        try
        {
            var order = new Order();
            var orderId = TryConvertInt64(CleanUpOrderId(tgOrder.order_number));

            if (orderId == null) continue;

            var tempOrderId = string.Format("{0}{1}", base.StoreId, orderId.Value);
            order.OrderId = TryConvertInt64(tempOrderId).Value;
            order.StoreOrderId = tgOrder.id.ToString();
            order.WarehouseOrderId = tgOrder.order_number;

            var orderFromDb = await orderMgr.GetOrderAsync(order.OrderId, base.StoreId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (orderFromDb != null) continue; // make sure we only import new order(i.e. doesn't exists in database)

            // shipping address
            var tgShippingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.shipping_address_id);
            if (tgShippingAddress == null) continue;

            order.ShipFirstName = tgShippingAddress.first_name;
            order.ShipLastName = tgShippingAddress.last_name;
            order.ShipCompanyName = tgShippingAddress.company_name;
            order.ShipAddress1 = tgShippingAddress.address1;
            order.ShipAddress2 = tgShippingAddress.address2;
            order.ShipCity = tgShippingAddress.suburb;
            order.ShipState = tgShippingAddress.state;
            order.ShipPostalCode = tgShippingAddress.zip_code;
            order.ShipCountry = tgShippingAddress.country;
            order.ShipPhoneNumber = tgShippingAddress.phone_number;

            order.CustomerEmail = tgOrder.email;

            // billing address
            var tgBillingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.billing_address_id);
            if (tgBillingAddress == null) continue;

            // line items
            var lineItems = GetOrderLineItems(tgOrder.id);
            foreach (TGOrderLineItem lineItem in lineItems)
            {
                var ol = new OrderLine();
                if (lineItem.variant_id.HasValue)
                {
                    var variant = GetVariant(lineItem.variant_id.Value);
                    if (variant == null) continue;
                    ol.ProductName = variant.product_name;
                    ol.SKU = variant.sku;
                    ol.ThreePLSKU = ol.SKU;
                    ol.Qty = Convert.ToInt16(TryGetDecimal(lineItem.quantity));
                    ol.OrderId = order.OrderId;
                    ol.Price = TryGetDecimal(lineItem.price);
                    ol.SubTotal = (ol.Qty * ol.Price);
                    ol.StoreOrderLineId = Convert.ToString(lineItem.id);
                    order.OrderLines.Add(ol);
                }
            }
            var validator = new Validator(base.Task);
            if (validator.IsValidOrder(order))
            {
                await orderMgr.AddAsync(order).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you just want to run the code in the background you can also just wrap it in a Task.Run

```
public async Task<List<Order> GetOrdersFromTradeGeckoCount()
{
        string orderLimit = base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.HasValue ? base.StorePlugin.Store.OrderLimit.Value.ToString() : "250";
        string filters = string.Format("?status=finalized&limit={0}", orderLimit);
        HttpResponseMessage response = _requestHelper.GetHttpResponse("orders" + filters);
        var tgOrders = GetOrdersResponse(response);
        //Async Convert and Save Order
        await ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(tgOrders).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return ConvertToORouterOrdersCount(tgOrders);
}

public Task ConvertToORouterOrdersAsync(List<TGOrder> tgOrders)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var orderMgr = new OrderDAC();
        var orders = new List<Order>(tgOrders.Count());
        foreach (TGOrder tgOrder in tgOrders)
        {
            try
            {
                var order = new Order();
                var orderId = TryConvertInt64(CleanUpOrderId(tgOrder.order_number));

                if (orderId == null) continue;

                var tempOrderId = string.Format("{0}{1}", base.StoreId, orderId.Value);
                order.OrderId = TryConvertInt64(tempOrderId).Value;
                order.StoreOrderId = tgOrder.id.ToString();
                order.WarehouseOrderId = tgOrder.order_number;

                var orderFromDb = await orderMgr.GetOrder(order.OrderId, base.StoreId);
                if (orderFromDb != null) continue; // make sure we only import new order(i.e. doesn't exists in database)

                // shipping address
                var tgShippingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.shipping_address_id);
                if (tgShippingAddress == null) continue;

                order.ShipFirstName = tgShippingAddress.first_name;
                order.ShipLastName = tgShippingAddress.last_name;
                order.ShipCompanyName = tgShippingAddress.company_name;
                order.ShipAddress1 = tgShippingAddress.address1;
                order.ShipAddress2 = tgShippingAddress.address2;
                order.ShipCity = tgShippingAddress.suburb;
                order.ShipState = tgShippingAddress.state;
                order.ShipPostalCode = tgShippingAddress.zip_code;
                order.ShipCountry = tgShippingAddress.country;
                order.ShipPhoneNumber = tgShippingAddress.phone_number;

                order.CustomerEmail = tgOrder.email;

                // billing address
                var tgBillingAddress = GetAddress(tgOrder.billing_address_id);
                if (tgBillingAddress == null) continue;

                // line items
                var lineItems = GetOrderLineItems(tgOrder.id);
                foreach (TGOrderLineItem lineItem in lineItems)
                {
                    var ol = new OrderLine();
                    if (lineItem.variant_id.HasValue)
                    {
                        var variant = GetVariant(lineItem.variant_id.Value);
                        if (variant == null) continue;
                        ol.ProductName = variant.product_name;
                        ol.SKU = variant.sku;
                        ol.ThreePLSKU = ol.SKU;
                        ol.Qty = Convert.ToInt16(TryGetDecimal(lineItem.quantity));
                        ol.OrderId = order.OrderId;
                        ol.Price = TryGetDecimal(lineItem.price);
                        ol.SubTotal = (ol.Qty * ol.Price);
                        ol.StoreOrderLineId = Convert.ToString(lineItem.id);
                        order.OrderLines.Add(ol);
                    }
                }
                var validator = new Validator(base.Task);
                if (validator.IsValidOrder(order))
                {
                    orderMgr.Add(order);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```